# Examples of great PhD Thesis and great PhD Plans to learn from?

Tags: phd, thesis

In order to understand if I really want and can pursue a PhD program I would like to see some real PhD Thesis and especially some real PhD plans from real world so I could at least approximately realize what the final product looks like (in terms of volume, structure, etc.) and what the real plan could be.

Why I'm asking:

- I'm thinking about making a PhD in AI/NLP
- Reading around the topic on the internet doesn't make it clear yet.
- Asking for some great works - mostly because at my level I probably wouldn't tell the great from not so great myself.

If in the time of doing your own PhD (or before or after that) you met some thesis/plan that really got you thinking "oh, that's what a great plan should look like, I definitely can learn a lot from it" - that would be what I'm looking for.

Sorry if the question is too naive.
Thanks!

Comment: What's a PhD plan, and how do you expect to learn a lot from one?

Answer (score 6):

Every university library keeps a copy of every PhD thesis from every PhD awarded at that institution. That's the place to start.

Comment: And, aside from the student and their committee (and maybe their mother), nobody reads them...

Comment: @JonCuster I read at least seven other people's PhD theses while I was studying for mine

Comment: Dissertations can be (not always, but can be) very well written documents-- often second drafts of already polished papers, mostly free from page limits (a very real thing in my field), and all collected with nice introductory and literature search sections.  They're not light reading, but sometimes you can find really clear descriptions and details in them.

Answer (score 5):

Go online to the university or universities you are interested in and search their repository of dissertations/theses. They are usually easy to find and freely accessible. Often they are organized using eCommons or another similar database/repository. [Here is one](https://digitalcommons.njit.edu/etd/) that comes up through a simple google search.

Unfortunately, I doubt anyone can point you to a specific example since most people do not make a habit of reading dissertations (except the committee that approved it).

I think it's also worth mentioning that while this will give you an idea of what a finished product looks like, you're not going to find the *plan* they followed to get there. In fact, the point of a dissertation is to produce a coherent product and so the finished version is going to look put together even if the road to get there was bumpy.

And, at least superficially, a "great" dissertation is going to look very similar to a not-so-great one. Most places have fairly specific formatting and content requirements (field, topic, and institution dependent) so even if you did find an objectively good one it might not be generalizable.

I think it's a fine idea to look at some dissertations/theses to get an idea of what you would need to produce. It seems like the real question is "how do I learn what *specifically* is expected to earn a PhD in field X", and the answer to that is to reach out to faculty at institutions you are interested in and ask them questions. See what they would be expecting, what their institution specific process is, how much support you will receive in the program etc...

Answer (score 3):

I would say that a great thesis and a very well planned PhD are not necessarily equivilent things. While a student who had a very clear plan throughout their candidature would likely produce a higher quality thesis than if they had less direction, I am sure there is not a direct relation between the two.

Due to the nature of research, no plan can guarantee sucsess, as this is down to many factors, not the least being some luck. The planning part of a PhD is largely dependant on the advisor of the project, as they are the ones with the existing expertise in the area (at least when you're beginning to work) and should be able to give advice and direction.

You have two separate things you can investigate, the first being the general quality of students work with the advisors you might be interested in working with. You have noted that it can be very difficult for you to gauge that right now, but if you see that these students produce well-cited works (this is not a true metric of quality of course, but it does at least show how popular these works in the community).

The second investigation could be, if appropriate, to speak to past students of these advisors. These students might be able to shed some insight into how their experience during their PhD was.